# Apache RewriteRule to only allow whitelist URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403, whitelist

I have three different categories of URLs. Each category has a specific set of URLs I want to allow and everything else should be forbidden. This is to lock my site down.

These are the categories and the regular expressions I came up with.
I'm using Apache 2.4.

**First category:**

```
http://example.org/foo
http://example.org/foo/bar
http://example.org/user
^/foo(/bar)?|user$
```

**Second category:**

```
http://example.org/baz/1?foo=bar
^/baz/[0-9]+\?foo=bar$
```

**Third category:**

```
http://example.org/search?bar=baz
^/search\?bar=baz$
```

**Here are the rewrite rules I came up with based on the above:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Category 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo(/bar)?|user$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

# Category 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/baz/[0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^foo=bar$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

# Category 3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^b=bar$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

The regular expressions look fine to me but as I was testing them at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, I noticed that the URL `http://example.org/foo` will be forbidden at the expression for Category 2. I understand why this happens but I'm not sure how to resolve this. I might be missing something here, can someone tell me how I should fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the white list first, and then restrict/forbid everything else:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:foo(?:/bar)?|user)/?$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=bar$
RewriteRule ^baz/\d+$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^b=bar$
RewriteRule ^search$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: That's for the no capture, right? Yeah, that would be good to have too, thanks. But that won't change the fact that the url `http://example.org/foo` would still fail at the expression for `Category 2`.

Comment: I actually did try it out when I responded. The URLs I have mentioned are the whitelist,, hence the negation in my expression. The problem is that even with the grouping you have made, it will still fail at the expression for Category #2 (just tested this again, to make sure). Try it out for yourself here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @Housni Updated the reply above. Please check. Sorry about the confusion previously.

Comment: No problem. I think the first rule should have the `!`, like `RewriteRule !^(?:foo(?:/bar)?|user)/?$ - [L]`. But even with that, if you tried `http://example.org/foo`, it would still fail on the last RewriteRule. I'm obviously doing something wrong here :/ Thanks.

Comment: @Housni no. With the current rules, you are first allowing all your whitelisted addresses and then, at the very end, blocking all other requests. Since you're using Apache 2.4, replace all `[L]` flags with `[END]`.

Comment: I think Apache 2.4 also allows the `L` flag. I might use that since [END](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) apparently prevent .htaccess from working too. BUt you're right, your solution worked. Thanks for taking the time :)